# dynamically name input type

Tags: php, mysql

I have a loop that creates a html table with specific number of rows defined by the user.
In the table there are a number of input types. I am looking to append the name with the row number so when the form containing the table  posted to another page, each input from each row is easily identified with row number, something like

```
name=somename.the row number taken from the loop
```

Is this possible? Would have put the code I am trying to use but it keeps telling me here that I have not identified code block using this that and the other but I did so also getting something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, try to put your whole code so it'll be easier for us. You can format a block of text as code by highlighting it and pressing Ctrl+K.

To solve your problem just create a variable outside of your loop like so:

```
$count = 1;
```

Then, at the end of your loop increment it:

```
$count++;
```

This way, you know that $count will have a value of 1 at first in your loop, then a value of 2, value of 3 and so on. Next you just need to do a concatenation of your name's row with the value of $count:

```
$name = 'row_name'.$count;
```